# How To I Explode From Array With Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I Want To Get ID From Link i have set all links in array and explode forward slash / and then loop it but i'm getting only one id main link in array 
`"/4tzCuIpHHhc/long-title-here",` i need this id `4tzCuIpHHhc`

i'm trying this

```
<?php 
$links = array(
"/WSNINQJZj1s/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-lee-sung-kyung-run-nam-joo-hyuk-errand-20161130",
"/Nmy5FWgX0S0/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-nam-joo-hyuk-reject-a-proposal-20161130",
"/u3gumA7-38A/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-did-you-fall-in-love-with-my-brother-20161130",
"/Zsa_saeRT1E/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-sung-kyung-offered-joo-hyuk-a-deal-20161130",
"/9q0uUfSr0lE/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-nam-joo-hyuks-angry-at-lee-sung-kyung-20161130",
"/UH6YqMDdMDE/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-sung-kyung-and-lee-jae-yoons-drive-date-20161130",
"/5pC2NJtCg_I/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep03-did-you-fight-because-of-me-20161123",
"/UbxbVugdIdo/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-lee-sung-kyung-fell-into-the-pool-20161116",
"/f29SpSqcOQc/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep03-lee-sung-kyung-got-into-trouble-20161123",
"/ydWm_Pnp1BQ/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep04-lee-sung-kyung-vs-nam-joo-hyuk-20161124",
"/uiLlQSexJr4/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-an-underwear-thiefs-identity-20161116",
"/4tzCuIpHHhc/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-weightlifter-vs-rhythmic-gymnast-20161116",
"/QzRi9_4-ItQ/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-lee-sung-kyung-enter-a-contest-instead20161130",
);

foreach ($links as $result) {    
    $explode_c = explode('/',$result);
        $s = $explode_c[1];
}
echo $s;

?>
```

Comment: Your code will only output one ID because it only does "echo" one time. If you want it to echo once for each result, you need to put the echo inside the foreach loop.

Comment: You're only getting one id because you're echo'ing after the loop.

Comment: @kainaw Thanks for Your Comment Problem Solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `$s` as array

```
  foreach ($links as $result) {    
        $explode_c = explode('/',$result);
            $s[] = $explode_c[1];
    }

print_r($s);
```

Comment: Thanks Working Fine For Me

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, replace your with below:

```
$links = array(
"/WSNINQJZj1s/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-lee-sung-kyung-run-nam-joo-hyuk-errand-20161130",
"/Nmy5FWgX0S0/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-nam-joo-hyuk-reject-a-proposal-20161130",
"/u3gumA7-38A/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-did-you-fall-in-love-with-my-brother-20161130",
"/Zsa_saeRT1E/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-sung-kyung-offered-joo-hyuk-a-deal-20161130",
"/9q0uUfSr0lE/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-nam-joo-hyuks-angry-at-lee-sung-kyung-20161130",
"/UH6YqMDdMDE/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-sung-kyung-and-lee-jae-yoons-drive-date-20161130",
"/5pC2NJtCg_I/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep03-did-you-fight-because-of-me-20161123",
"/UbxbVugdIdo/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-lee-sung-kyung-fell-into-the-pool-20161116",
"/f29SpSqcOQc/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep03-lee-sung-kyung-got-into-trouble-20161123",
"/ydWm_Pnp1BQ/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep04-lee-sung-kyung-vs-nam-joo-hyuk-20161124",
"/uiLlQSexJr4/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-an-underwear-thiefs-identity-20161116",
"/4tzCuIpHHhc/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep01-weightlifter-vs-rhythmic-gymnast-20161116",
"/QzRi9_4-ItQ/weightlifting-fairy-kim-bok-ju-ep05-lee-sung-kyung-enter-a-contest-instead20161130",
);

foreach ($links as $result) {    
    $explode_c = explode('/',$result);
        $s[] = $explode_c[1]; // made array of exploded string
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($s);

$result = array_search('4tzCuIpHHhc', $s); // search for the string if you need key from $s
echo $id = $s[11];// $result = 11
```